# Widescreen web camera will only show in standard definition in Cheese

Tags: webcam, cheese

How do I make it show in a wide screen resolution?

The Camera is a Logitech C270.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try changing the resolution.

(You've probably tried this but it's worth mentioning)

[image: Screenshot]